# Pandas -- set row values based on values in another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables in pandas. One is about 10,000+ rows that looks like this:

Table 1

```
col_1      date      state  ratio [50 more cols]
   A       10/12      NY     .5
   A       12/05      MA     NaN
   .........
```

I have another table that's about 10 rows that looks like this:

Table 2

```
date     state    ratio
12/05    MA       .9
12/03    MA       .8
............
```

I need to set the ratio in table 1 based on the date and state values from table 2. The ideal solution would be to merge on date and state, but that creates two columns: ratio_x and ratio_y

**I need a way to set the ratio in table 1 to the corresponding ratio in table 2 where the date and states both match. The ratios in table 1 can be overwritten.**

If this can be done correctly by merging then that works too.

**Edit:** You can consider table 2 as being meant to map to specific state values (so all the states in table 2 are MA in this example)

Comment: "creates two columns" - so what? Drop one of the columns and rename the other.

Comment: It might not be the most elegant or short-handed way, but you could create a column concatenating the date and state, then set the ratio column in Table 1 to the ratio in Table 2 using that date-state column as your index. Like DYZ said, you can always drop the additional column if you don't need it.

Comment: I need the values in both columns.

I've edited the question to reflect this. Basically, if there's a match for state and date, overwrite the ratio whether it's a value or NaN. Otherwise I need to keep the value that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to choose which `ratio` value to take first. Assuming you want ratios from table 2 to take precedence:

```
# join in ratio from the other table
table1 = table1.join(table2.set_index(["date", "state"])["ratio"].to_frame("ratio2"), on=["date", "state"])

# take ratio2 first, then the existing ratio value if ratio2 is null
table1["ratio"] = table1["ratio2"].fillna(table1["ratio"])

# delete the ratio2 column
del table1["ratio2"]
```

Comment: I get an error that I'm merging on object and datetime64[ns] columns. This didn't happen with a normal merge and I'm assuming it's because date was set to an index

Comment: "You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

In the step before this, I made sure date in both tables are the same type, and I have been able to merge using date before so I don't think it's an actual data type issue but something that comes up when it's set to an index

Comment: Are you sure? What happens when you run `table1["date"].dtype == table2["date"].dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

First create a mapping series from `df2`:

```
s = df2.set_index(['date', 'state'])['ratio']
```

Then feed to `df1`:

```
df1['ratio'] = df1.set_index(['date', 'state']).index.map(s.get)\
                  .fillna(df1['ratio'])
```

Precedence is given to ratios in `df2`.

Comment: Doesn't .get need a value?
As is I get "TypeError: 'value' must be a scalar, passed: Series"