# Canonical way for Pandas set value based on reference table

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, a reference table and a main table. I want to map the values in the reference table to the main table, overwriting if necessary. In visual form:

[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

ref_data = {'Fruit':['Apple','Pear','Orange'],
            'Price':[50,60,70]}

reference_table = pd.DataFrame(ref_data)

main_data = {'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],
             'col2':[5,5,5,5,5],
             'Fruit':['Durian','Pineapple','Apple','Orange','Pear'],
             'Price':[40,120,454,12,43]}

main_data = pd.DataFrame(main_data)
```

This seems like quite a common use case.I found the following question that seems to exactly fit, but it seems a bit "hacky" in a sense. Just wondering if theres a proper way to do this?

[Pandas -- set row values based on values in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621168/pandas-set-row-values-based-on-values-in-another-table)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We usually use `np.where`

```
s=reference_table.set_index('Fruit').Price.reindex(main_data.Fruit).values
main_data['Price']=np.where(np.isnan(s),main_data['Price'],s)
```

Comment: The second bit overwrites the price column with the fruit names, is it supposed to be `..main_data['Price'],s)` at the end?

Comment: When I use this on my actual dataset i get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. I think the first line creates duplicate indexes somehow..?

Answer (score 0):

You can also merge and assign then drop the unused columns

`main_data = main_data.merge(reference_table, on='Fruit', how='left').assign(Price=lambda x: x['Price_y'].fillna(x['Price_x'])).drop(['Price_x', 'Price_y'], axis=1)`

Result

```
       Fruit  col1  col2  Price
0     Durian     1     5   40.0
1  Pineapple     2     5  120.0
2      Apple     3     5   50.0
3     Orange     4     5   70.0
4       Pear     5     5   60.0
```